# Issue with loading vtt from cross domain

Tags: html, video, html5-video, cross-domain, webvtt

I have issue with loading vtt from cross domain: "Unsafe attempt to load URL Domains... protocols and ports must match."
I tried to add crossorigin="true" to the video, it's working in chrome and firefox but it's not working in the Internet Explorer 11.
Is there other way to get vtt file from cross domain in IE11?

```
<video controls autoplay crossorigin="true">
     <source src="http://ronallo.com/demos/webvtt-cue-settings/soybean-talk-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <track label="Captions" kind="captions" srclang="en" src="http://ronallo.com/demos/webvtt-cue-settings/soybean-talk-clip.vtt" id="caption-change-track" default="">
  </video>
```

Comment: I have never gotten this to work properly no matter what suggestion I've followed.

Answer (score 17):

The `crossorigin` attribute on the `video` needs to be `anonymous` or `use-credentials`

```
<video controls autoplay crossorigin="use-credentials">
  <source src="http://ronallo.com/demos/webvtt-cue-settings/soybean-talk-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <track label="Captions" kind="captions" srclang="en" src="http://ronallo.com/demos/webvtt-cue-settings/soybean-talk-clip.vtt" id="caption-change-track" default="">
</video>
```

[Mozilla's explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

> **crossorigin**
>
> This enumerated attribute indicates whether to use CORS to fetch the related image. CORS-enabled resourcescan be reused in the  element without being tainted. The allowed values are:
>
> **anonymous**
>
> Sends a cross-origin request without a credential. In other words, it sends the Origin: HTTP header without a cookie, X.509 certificate, or performing HTTP Basic authentication. If the server does not give credentials to the origin site (by not setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: HTTP header), the image will be tainted, and its usage restricted.
>
> **use-credentials**
>
> Sends a cross-origin request with a credential. In other words, it sends the Origin: HTTP header with a cookie, a certificate, or performing HTTP Basic authentication. If the server does not give credentials to the origin site (through Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: HTTP header), the image will be tainted and its usage restricted.
>
> When not present, the resource is fetched without a CORS request (i.e. without sending the Origin: HTTP header), preventing its non-tainted used in  elements. If invalid, it is handled as if the enumerated keyword anonymous was used. See CORS settings attributes for additional information.

Comment: Thank you! Adding `crossorigin="anonymous"` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set a cross domain policy on the originating server by including the following header in the response when vtt files are requested:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

You can also restrict the allowed domains to specific entries if desired.

From the client side you can't force an over-ride, though correctly setting the `crossorigin` attribute (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes) - in this case to `anonymous` does help the browser negotiate the request correctly