# Localhost crossorigin issue - Unsafe attempt to load URL - Domains, protocols and ports must match

Tags: html5-video, cross-domain

I have a video control on a `localhost` with closed captions. I have the virtual host `static` defined that points to the same directory as `localhost`. Static feeds my media files and has worked forever... except it seems with video caption files.

If the track `src` is set to `static`, the captions won't show. Chrome console gives the error:

> Unsafe attempt to load URL https://static/file.vtt from the frame with URL
> https://localhost/page.php. Domains, protocols, and ports must match.

I've tried the advice at the post [issue-with-loading-vtt-from-cross-domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55645393/issue-with-loading-vtt-from-cross-domain) and set both values for `cross-origin` with no luck. Is this a `localhost` only issue? Any solutions to this?

```
video.crossorigin="anonymous";
video.crossorigin="use-credentials";
```

Comment: Does your address bar say `https://static/page.php` just before you try to load the VTT? If not, then there will be a CORS error (basically, what you're getting now). Image/video/audio loading is exempt from CORS (though you cannot "sample" the data. eg: no screen grabbing of a video). **Solution**: You fix by making sure `page.php` and `file.vtt` are coming from the in **same domain** (eg: if each file was opened in a new tab then they should have matching server names).